# How to start/configure JBoss clustering

Tags: cluster, jboss, failovercluster

I am totally new to JBoss. Basically i am needed to setup a JBoss clustering environment on windows. Meaning, JBossA sits on machine A and JBossB sits on machine B. So when JBossA fails, it will redirect the clients to JBossB.

I have downloaded the enterprise-installer-5.0.1.jar. After which, I have totally no idea on how to go about setting up the cluster. What are the steps that i should do?? Or what other files do i need to download too...

Any guide will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to do a lot more reading.

What you're trying to do (JBoss Failover) has infact not much to do with JBoss Clustering.

If you put, for instance, an Apache httpd in front of your JBosses, you can forward client requests to the app servers using `mod_proxy_ajp`. If you add `mod_proxy_balancer` to that, you have a working failover and loadbalancing setup.

JBoss Clustering only comes into play at the point where you want to do session replication, distributed caching etc.

Using the `all` profile (`run.sh/run.bat -c all`) as a starting point will already get you a working JBoss cluster, running with default settings and probably doing a lot more than you'll ever use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply... I don't really get what you meant by if u run the profile (run.sh/run.bat -c all), i am already in a JBoss cluster?? Then where do i do the "adding" of nodes into the cluster??

Comment: The nodes will automatically discover each other via Multicast. http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/4/html/clustering-intro-def.html